# Join html, css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, inline

Good day everyone,

Have one problem, source from here,

```
    <div class="offer offer-blocked">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1oc4.jpg"></img>
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.windows-help-support.com"    data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

    .offer-blocked {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    top:0;
    left:0;
  }
  img {
    @width: 10px;
    filter: blur(@width);
    // Browser Specific
    -webkit-filter: blur(@width);
    -moz-filter: blur(@width);
    -o-filter: blur(@width);
    -ms-filter: blur(@width);
  }
  .fb-like {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 30%;
    margin-left:-20px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .fb-like:after {
    content:"Please click on the LIKE button to unlock the OFFER";
   display:'block';
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
   top: 50px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: verdana;
  }
}

    jQuery( function() {

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
// Don't use my app id, use your own or it won't work!
 FB.init({appId: '134385103436857', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml:  true});


    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
      console.dir(href);
      console.dir(widget);
    jQuery(".offer.offer-blocked").removeClass("offer-blocked");
    jQuery(".fb-like").hide();
  });
};
(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&                       appId=134385103436857";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

``});
```

What I need to do is put all this code together into the HTML.
This will be later in a wordpress.COM webpage.

Tried to put the code inside of the HTML, inside the  and adding the styles inline, but this did not work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you put your css into <style></style> tag and js into <script></script> ? Can you develop your problem?

Comment: better is put style and script to other files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the basic structure of html, in html you can include the `<style>` and `<script>` tags.

But you can put styles and scripts in separate files and reference in html,
 see [script](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp) and [style](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style.asp) attributes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <style type="text/css">
           /*Your style here.*/
       </style>
       <script type="text/javascript">
            //Your script goes here
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem on two case: 
   first: (is not recommended but you can do this) 
you put into tags  your style class 
and put into tags  your code js as bellow

```
    .offer-blocked {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    top:0;
    left:0;
  }
  img {
    @width: 10px;
    filter: blur(@width);
    // Browser Specific
    -webkit-filter: blur(@width);
    -moz-filter: blur(@width);
    -o-filter: blur(@width);
    -ms-filter: blur(@width);
  }
  .fb-like {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 30%;
    margin-left:-20px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .fb-like:after {
    content:"Please click on the LIKE button to unlock the OFFER";
   display:'block';
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
   top: 50px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: verdana;
  }
}

</style>
<script>
jQuery( function() {

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
// Don't use my app id, use your own or it won't work!
 FB.init({appId: '134385103436857', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml:  true});


    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
      console.dir(href);
      console.dir(widget);
    jQuery(".offer.offer-blocked").removeClass("offer-blocked");
    jQuery(".fb-like").hide();
  });
};
(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&                       appId=134385103436857";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

``});
</script>

<div class="offer offer-blocked">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1oc4.jpg"></img>
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.windows-help-support.com"    data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

Or second solution is: 
put your code js to new file js and add this file using `<script src="link_to_file_js"></script>` and put your code css to new file css and add this file using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="link_to_css_file">`.
This 
For examlpe:

```
<body>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="link_to_css_file">
      <script src="link_to_file_js"></script>
   </head>
   ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create separate files for CSS and Script and use the following lines of code in order to implement it onto your webpage.

CSS:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="assets/css/main.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
```